# Getting a regex to match sentence in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows

I am trying to extract this ("5013a27a-3e44d69d-4120-080027a10080" varies)

```
/vmfs/volumes/5013a27a-3e44d69d-4120-080027a10080
```

out of this (which is a string):

```
name                 datastore1
url                  /vmfs/volumes/5013a27a-3e44d69d-4120-080027a10080
capacity             123480309760
freeSpace            96355745792
accessible           1
type                 VMFS
multipleHostAccess   <unset>
```

So I have done the following, but its not working:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[/][A-Za-z0-9/-][/] [ ]");
MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(input);
```

where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Just about everywhere :) That regex will match `/p/  `, and not much else.

Comment: [Espresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) anyone ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
@"/([A-Za-z0-9/-]+)"
```

Get the value of group 1.

Comment: Thanks, but what does the + on its own mean?

Comment: @user1559618: It's not on its own. It means "match one or more occurrences of the preceding item". So a literal slash, followed by a group containing one or more letters, numbers or dashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = Regex.Match(text, @"url\s+(.+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

I believe this to be more reliable then searching for a slash. `\s` matches any whitespace character, which will take care of the whitespace between "url" and the value.